# I have an error accessing DocuSign signing URL with Webview

Tags: android, webview, docusignapi

I am currently testing the DocuSign API with the Demo Sandbox.
I have a WebAPI in C# which uses the DocuSign API. I create an enveloppe containing the document to sign and generate the recipient View URL.

I also have an Android App with a Webview which is supposed to get the generated URL to permit the user to sign the document.

When the webview loads the URL, the error ERR_CONNECTION_RESET occurs.

I precise that it works well using the Android Emulator but not with my phone connected in WI-FI.

Thanks in advance.

I copy/pasted the URL to my phone browser and it works. It's only within the App and the Webview that I can reach it.

I expect to reach the Docusign signing page related to my Document.

The WebView shows an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

EDIT : 
Here is some code

```java
     myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest url) {
                if((url.getUrl()).toString().equals(Constant.URL + "?event=signing_complete"))
                {
                   /*Some code to redirect to other activity*/
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("url",rep);
                    myWebView.loadUrl(rep);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
                //myWebView.loadUrl(rep);
                Log.d("ERROR",  error.getErrorCode());
            }

            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                Log.i("SSL", "SSL error");
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });
```

[here is the result in the webview][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRuly.png

EDIT 2 :
If it can help, My .NET WEB API is hosted on my computer with Windows IIS and is connected to the network through Ethernet.

The Android device is connected via WI-FI to the same network.
I don't know if the error is because of the usage of SSL to access the signing page of Docusign.

I tried to replace the url of the webview by google.com and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem but still don't understand the reasons.

I manually uninstalled the application from the device.

I reinstalled it and it worked, just feels so stupid that I didn't try that at first...

"Have you tried turning it off and on again ?"

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you added some code, so we can easily trace the error.
Have you tried adding

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

to your web view?